# What is stopping criteria for Newtons Method?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, newton-series

> Use newtons method to find solutions accurate to within $10^{-4}$ for the following: $$\\x^3-2x^2-5=0,\qquad[1,4]$$

Using : $p_{0}=2.0$

$\Rightarrow $ [image]

My question for the newtons method is what is the stopping criteria for it? How does one derive the function value? Does one use $$\\ \frac{|P_{n}-P_{n-1}|}{|P_n|}$$ or $$|P_{n}-P_{n-1}|$$

Comment: It generally depends the actual application that is using the method. However I would say the second one is more often used in computer programs as it guarantees a precision of the number.

Comment: How does one get $8.2$?$|3.25-2.0|=1.25$

Comment: sub in 3.25 into the function

Comment: Why do you substitute it into the function?

Comment: To compute the next Newton value?

Comment: I thought we were suppose to subtract $|P_{1}-P_{0}|$

Comment: You need $f(P_0)$ to compute $P_1$ in Newton's method.

Comment: Is this only for newtons method and its extensions? Is this done only for $f(0)$? What about $f(1),f(2),f(3)...$ f= function value.

Comment: I have extended my answer with information related to commonly used termination criteria.

Comment: @Harry49 Sadly, there was a glitch and your link to the relevant question was broken. Would you copy the link in a new comment?

Comment: @Jon. Considering $|f(pn)|<ε$ is very dangerous. Instead of solving $f(x)=0$, solve $10^{−99}f(x)=0$ and only one iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are searching for the roots of a polynomial $p$. In this case it is possible to compute a running error bound for $p$, i.e. a number $\mu$ such that the computed value $\hat{y}$ of $y = p(x)$ satisfies $$|y - \hat{y}| \leq \mu u,$$ where $u$ is the unit round off error. When the error bound exceeds the absolute value of $\hat{y}$ there is no point in doing additional iterations.

The running error bound depends on the algorithm used to evaluate $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$. Horner's method computes $$p_0 = a_n, \quad p_i = x p_{i-1} + a_{n-i}, \quad i = 1,2,\dotsc,n.$$ If $a_i$ and $x$ are machine numbers, then a running error bound can be computed concurrently as follows 
$$\mu_0 = 0, \quad z_j = p_{j-1} x, \quad p_j = z_j + a_{n-j}, \quad \mu_j = \mu_{j-1} |x| + |z_j| + |p_j|, \quad j=1,2,\dotsc, n.$$
The algorithm returns $y = p_n$ and $\mu = \mu_n$. It is possible, to reduce the cost of this algorithm from 5n flops to 4n flops, but this is not a critical issue at this juncture.

In the general case where your function is not a polynomial you must proceed with caution.

Ideally, you merge a rapidly convergent routine such as Newton's method or the secant method with the bisection method and maintain a bracket around the root. If you trust the sign of the computed values of $y = f(x)$, then you have a robust way of estimating the error. Here a running error bound or interval arithmetic can be helpful.

I must caution you against using the correction $$\Delta x \approx - f'(x)/f(x)$$ as an error estimate. If $0 = f(x + \Delta x)$, then by Taylor's theorem
$$0 = f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x + \frac{1}{2} f''(\xi_x) (\Delta x)^2 $$ for some $\xi_x$ between $x$ and $x + \Delta x$. It follows, that $\Delta x \approx - f'(x)/f(x)$ is a good approximation only when the second order term can be ignored. This is frequently the case, but I would not count on it in general.

Occasionally, it is helpful to remember that Newton's method exhibits one sided convergence in the limit, i.e. if the root is a simple, then the residuals $f(x_n)$ eventually have the same sign. Deviation from this behavior indicates that you are pushing against the limitations imposed by floating point arithmetic.

EDIT: Newton's and other iterative methods are frequently terminated when either  $$|f(x_n)| < \epsilon$$ or $$|x_n - x_{n-1}| < \delta$$
where $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are user-defined thresholds. This is a dangerous practice which is unsuited for general purpose software. A specific example is the equation $$f(x) = 0,$$
where $f(x) = \exp(-\lambda x)$ and $\lambda > 0$. Obviously, there are no solutions, but this is not the point. Newton's method yields $$x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{\lambda} \rightarrow \infty, \quad n \rightarrow \infty$$
It follows that the residual will eventually drop below the user's threshold. Moreover, if $\lambda$ is large enough, then the routine will immediately exit "succesfully", because $x_{n+1} - x_n$ is small enough.

Writing a robust nonlinear solver is a nontrivial exercise. You have to maintain a bracket around the root. You must be able to trust at least the computed signs. To that end, the user must supply not only a function which computes $f$, but also a reliable error bound.

Comment: $|f(p_n)|<  ε,$ is another way to find stopping criteria.

Comment: @Jon I have added a paragraph explaining why monitoring the residual is not sufficient for general purpose software.

Comment: @CarlChristian. $|f(p_n)|<  ε$ is very dangerous. Instead of solving $f(x)=0$, solve $10^{-99}f(x)=0$ and only one iteration.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Your comment was meant for Jon, right?

Comment: It was after reading the first expression in your edit.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici As far as I know, Jon will not be notified, unless you direct the comment to him. The post owner (in this case me) will always be notified.

Answer (score 1):

Without computing higher derivatives the best estimate for the momentaneous error $\xi-x_n$ is the size of the next correction, namely $-{f(x_n)\over f'(x_n)}$. After all, if there would be a better estimate of the error using the available information, one would use this better estimate instead for the correction. In numerical praxis this means that one stops after the first correction which is smaller than the desired accuracy.

Comment: In addition one could check that in the last one or two iteration steps the function values decrease by at least a factor of 2. Then the probability is high that the iteration has reached a region of quadratic convergence.

Comment: Forgive me, but I think it is possible to misunderstand your answer. Why? There exists modified Newton methods which exhibit third order convergence. They need an extra function evaluation for each iteration, but they do not require higher order derivatives. In this sense, your first sentence is not true. If "the available information" refers to $f(x_n)$ and $f'(x_n)$, rather than our ability to compute extra values, then your second statement rectifies the matter. I have updated my own answer with an example explaining why tracking the difference between iterates is not a reliable method.